audio file creating with zero sizes in IOS with flutter sound 9.17.8
i want to create a .wav or  .aac or .m4a file for audio sound in ios flutter and same is working fine in android but not able to play files in ios flutter.
i have  to create a .wav or  .aac or .m4a file for audio sound in ios flutter and same is working fine in android but not able to play files in ios flutter.

Show what you have done. Share some code.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

i am using flutter_sound: ^9.17.8 for record audio in android and ios , so in android i am able to genrate a audio file with some sound , while in ios i am not able to genrate a audio file with sound , file is created but its showing 0 byte size , so please suggest to to fix it

i think i found this error #0   FlutterSoundRecorder.log (package:flutter_sound/public/flutter_sound_recorder.dart:290:13)
flutter: │ #1   MethodChannelFlutterSoundRecorder.channelMethodCallHandler. (package:flutter_sound_platform_interface/method_channel_flutter_sound_recorder.dart:117:24) please suggest

please suggest not able to record sound files to document directory .
